# A group of order $12$, which has no subgroups of order $6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Assume $G$ is a group of order $12$ having no subgroup of order $6$, and let $h_1,h_2\in G$ distinct of order $2$, prove that their product must be also of order $2$ ?

Suppose $(h_1h_2)^3=e_G$ then ;

$\{e_G\ ,h_1\ ,h_2\ ,h_1h_2\ ,h_2h_1\ ,h_1h_2h_1\}$ forms a subgroup of order $6$ which contradicts the assumption. I have to show that the elements are really distinct.

$\bullet$ $h_1h_2\neq h_2h_1$ otherwise:

$(h_1h_2)^3=h_1h_2h_1h_2h_1h_2=h_1h_2\overset!=e_G\implies h_1=h_2^{-1}$ but $h_1^2=e_G$, thus $h_1=h_2$ (contradiction again)

the others are distinct due to cancellation law

$\textbf{My question:}$ I took here the exponent $3$ and constructed a subgroup with $6$ elements, Can I extend it for general $n$, i.e. exponent $n\implies\exists$ subgroup with $2n$ elements ? (Then I could use Lagrange's law to prove the claim.)

Comment: Do I have to check it step by step ?